# Replace value and previous value if condition is met in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset that looks like this:

`df <- matrix(c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 3.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 4, 0.3, 1.2), nrow=5, ncol=2)`

(This is a simplified example)

I would like to write a function or loop that checks if each value (t) or its previous value (t-1) are bigger than 3, and that replaces **both** t and t-1 with NA if **either one** of them is bigger than 3.

The desired outcome would thus look something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given what you've said, shouldn't there be NA entries in the [5, 1] and [4, 2] positions as well? You said that the entries in positions t and t-1 should be replaced with NA if either is bigger than 3; for the entries I referenced, that was true of the t-1 position. (It's the "either one" chunk of your request that seems inconsistent with your desired output to me.)

Comment: Also: is there any significance in the matrix structure, or should this check "wrap around" (i.e. if the [1, 2] entry was 3.6, then both it and the [5, 1] entry should be replaced with NA)?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery You are right of course, thanks. I didn't even realise that. I have adapted the desired output. There is no wrap-around, in my dataset each column represents a different stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution which should yield your desired outcome. Note, that since there is no "wrap-around" in your desired output, I turned the matrix into a `data.frame`.

```r
# your data
df <-matrix(c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 3.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 4, 0.3, 1.2), nrow=5, ncol=2)

# needs to be converted to a data.frame 
df <- as.data.frame(df)

# recode function
recode_df <- function(x) { 
  x2 <- c(NA,x[-length(x)])
  x3 <- c(x[-1], NA)
  replace(x, (x > 3 | x2 > 3 | x3 > 3), NA)
}

# apply recode function on all columns
as.data.frame(lapply(df, recode_df))
#>    V1  V2
#> 1 0.2 0.3
#> 2 0.5  NA
#> 3  NA  NA
#> 4  NA  NA
#> 5  NA 1.2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>